# Looping with qplot / ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a bunch of variables against each other by using a loop and `par(ask=T)` to just update the plot after each mouse click.

The following code works fine using the `plot()` function:

```
require(ggplot2)
df1 <- data.frame(id=seq(1,10,1)
    ,col1 = runif(10)
    ,col2 = runif(10)
    ,col3 = runif(10)
    ,col4 = runif(10)
    ,col5 = runif(10)
    ,col6 = runif(10)
    ,col7 = runif(10)
    ,col8 = runif(10)
    ,col9 = runif(10)
    ,col10 = runif(10)
    )

par(ask=TRUE)
for(i in 2:9){
colName2 <- paste("col",i,sep="")
plot(df1$col1, df1[,colName2])
flush.console()
}
par(ask=FALSE)
```

However if I run the same code and use `qplot()` instead of `plot()`, the plot window never updates.

Any ideas why or workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot2` graphs are not displayed just by a call to `qplot` (or `ggplot`); when the value returned by this function is printed (as it is by default when issued on the command line), then the plot is drawn. Within a loop, the return value of a function is not printed by default, so nothing is shown. Explicitly print it, and it will show up.

This is covered in [R FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f).

```
par(ask=TRUE)
for(i in 2:9){
  colName2 <- paste("col",i,sep="")
  print(qplot(df1$col1, df1[,colName2]))
  flush.console()
}
par(ask=FALSE)
```